# Set youngest timestamp in sql one-to-many relation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'v got a table "one" and a table "many" with these structure:

```
one.id integer
one.updated_on timestamp
```

```
many.id integer
many.one_id integer references one(id)
many.updated_on timestamp
```

I need a statemant to update `one.updated_on` with the youngest value of `many.updated_on` with `many.one_id = one.id`

DB is postgresql if its important for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `JOIN` in an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE one
    SET updated_on = m.max_updated_on
    FROM (SELECT many.one_id, MAX(many.updated_on) as max_updated_on
          FROM many
          GROUP BY many.one_id
         ) m
    WHERE m.one_id = one.one_id AND
          one.updated_on IS DISTINCT FROM m.max_updated_on;
```

Comment: I think in line 2 it should be `m.max_updated_on` instead of `m.min_updated_on`

Answer (score 0):

update one set updated_on = (
    select max(updated_on) from many where many.one_id = one.id
)
where one.column_to_filter = ...
    and one.other_column_to_filter_if_exists = ...